# Solucionar concatenacion de elementos document

Tags: javascript

No puedo recorrer el for. ya que las variables que almacenan los document elementos no se concatenan. Lo que busco es hacer un contador de las a que estan dentro del id menu y su li.

```js
addEventListener('click',eventoE,false);

function eventoE(e) {
 // e.preventDefault();
 var div = document.getElementById('menu');
 var ve = div.getElementsByTagName('li');
 var a = ve.getElementsByTagName('a');

 for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  console.log(ve);
  document.write(ve);
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Comentarios</title>
  <script src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="menu">
           
    <li><a href="#">Enlaces creados 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagina1.php?fecha=12-10-2018">Enlaces creados 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagina1.php?fecha=13-10-2018">Enlaces creados 3</a></li>
  </div>
  <div id="container" style="border : 1px solid red;padding: 60px;width: 300px; margin: 20px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Puedes especificar mas en concreto que es lo que necesitas? Y que es lo que no te sale? Para así poder ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que entendí fue que dado un tag con algun identificador (id menu), quieres contar los tags li y a contenidos. Una alternativa de solucion podría ser:

```js
 document.addEventListener('click',EventoE,false);

  function EventoE(e)
  {
    var div = document.getElementById('menu');
    var li = div.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var countA = 0;

    for(var i=0;i<li.length;i++)
    {
        var tagA = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a');//obtiene los tags a dentro del tag li

        if(tagA.length != 0 )//verifica existencia de tag a
          countA +=1;
    }
    console.log('Cantidad de tags LI:'+li.length);
    console.log('Cantidad de tags A :'+countA);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Comentarios</title>
  <!-- <script src="ajax.js"></script> -->

</head>
<body>
  <div id="menu">

    <li><a href="#">Enlaces creados 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagina1.php?fecha=12-10-2018">Enlaces creados 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagina1.php?fecha=13-10-2018">Enlaces creados 3</a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><a href="pagina1.php?fecha=13-10-2018">Enlaces creados 3</a></li>

  </div>

  <div id="container" style="border : 1px solid red;padding: 60px;width: 300px; margin: 20px;"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oye! y como seria si usas un array asi :  div = document.getElementById('menu');
var vec = div.getElementsByTagName('li');
var a = vec[].getElementsByTagName('a');

Answer (score 1):

Por que no haces un selector directo a los elementos que necesitas con `querySelectorAll`, tu código se ve más elegante si lo pones así.

```js
addEventListener('click',eventoE,false);

function eventoE( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let count  = document.getElementById('menu').querySelectorAll('li a');
 for( var i = 0; i < count.length; i++ ){
      console.log( count[ i ] );
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Comentarios</title>
  <script src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="menu">
           
    <li><a href="#">Enlaces creados 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagina1.php?fecha=12-10-2018">Enlaces creados 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="pagina1.php?fecha=13-10-2018">Enlaces creados 3</a></li>
  </div>
  <div id="container" style="border : 1px solid red;padding: 60px;width: 300px; margin: 20px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, es buena tu ayuda pero estoy estudiando a pie y luego meto codigos mas limpios; lo hago para aprender bien me entiendes. ahorita estoy es siguiendo unos pasos por eso es que no se porque las variables no me retornan nada para hacer el contador en el for

Comment: si me ayudas te dare los punts restantes

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es porque; no se unen las variables para buscar el tag de ( a )